# Generate a QR image with URL parameters

Tags: html, url, qr-code

I'm in need of generating a QR image - but the URL needs to include parameters.

I've tried Googles:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=http://www.me.com/me.asp?i=1&n=2
```

...but the image generated, only links to:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=http://www.me.com/me.asp?i=1
```

I.e. Without n=2 at the end.

Does anyone know how to generate a QR image, which will allow more than one parameter?

Comment: For others to find in the future, here's the documentation - https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to [url encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding) the ampersand character `&` , which is `%26` encoded, so it gets not confused with the normal `&` ampersand character used to separate the variables in your google url, so use this:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=http://www.me.com/me.asp?i=1%26n=2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nelson - exactly the fix I was looking for - cheers